# Regex to Capture IPaddr but not MIB

Tags: regex, perl

My Data is freeform text.  I'm scanning that data for IP addresses. I'm using the following regex:

```
(   # first 3 ip (with optional [.] (.) \{.\} )
    (?: (?: 25[0-5] | 2[0-4][0-9] | [01]?[0-9][0-9]? ) \(* \[* \{* \. \)* \]* \}* ){3}
    # last octet
    (?: 25[0-5] | 2[0-4][0-9] | [01]?[0-9][0-9]? )
)
```

This works great until the text contains something like:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0: blah, blah, blah
```

then I get the following matches:

```
1.
3.6.1.2
1.1.1.0
```

What kind of modification to the regex do I need to make?  Perl RE if it matters.

Sample Data:

```
This is the IP I want 10.12.1.23, but when I did the snmp walk the 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 variable came back null.
```

Desired capture:

```
10.12.1.23
```

Comment: Not sure if regex would be the best approach. Have you seen [Data::Valdidate:IP](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Data-Validate-IP-0.23/lib/Data/Validate/IP.pm)?

Comment: Looks like a job for negative lookahead.

Comment: You've pointed out what you don't want to match, but what would you want to match in that instance (if anything)?

Comment: You could add anchors `^` and `$`

Comment: I'll update question, but I'm using the regex to extract.

Comment: Anchors won't work because IP addr could be anywhere in line.

Comment: Do you have a sample of text to test against? http://regex101.com/r/cA3eS3/2

Comment: Please can you explain what text you need to match where you have to ignore brackets between the octets?

Comment: the ip address are sometimes entered at 10[.]12[.]1[.]23 or using () or {}

Comment: You probably want to prepend `\b` to just before your `(?:...)` on the first 3 IP, and then append `\b` to just after your closing `(?:...)` on the last octet, to exclude cases like `9999.0.0.0` (it matches the last 2 `99` in `9999`).

Comment: @Todd: Okay I get it, and have modified my answer accordingly. It's a bit strange though - I don't think I've ever seen anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example ensures that the matching string isn't preceded or followed by a dot `.` or a decimal digit.

<strike>I don't understand what you mean by the brackets so I haven't added code for that.</strike>

Okay I get the brackets thing now. I've added another regex for the separator and included it in the final regex. Seems to work fine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = <<END_TEXT;
This is the IP I want 10.12.1.23, but when I did the
snmp walk the 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 variable came back null.
END_TEXT

my $octet_re     = qr/(?: 25[0-5] | 2[0-4][0-9] | [01]?[0-9]?[0-9] )/x;
my $separator_re = qr/(?: \. | \Q(.)\E | \Q[.]\E | \Q{.}\E )/x;
my $ip_re        = qr/(?: (?: $octet_re  $separator_re ){3} $octet_re )/x;

print $1, "\n" while $s =~ /(?<! [0-9.] ) ($ip_re) (?! [0-9.] )/xg;
```

**output**

```
10.12.1.23
```

Comment: @Todd: Note that I've modified it to insist that there is *neither a dot nor a decimal digit* before or after the IP address. It will still match oddities like the first four fields from `99[.]99[.]99[.]99[.]99[.]99[.]99` but I guess that's not possible?

Comment: Thanks Borodin.  this has vastly improved by extraction.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hZ4eE7/1)

Regex: `(?<!\.)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?!\.)`

It capture 4 groups of digits (1 to 3) not preceded by a dot or followed by a dot.

Edit: was to show the lookahead and lookbehind, replace the \d{1,3} with your original regex to match IP specificaly if really needed

Answer (score 0):

Using negative lookahead and lookbehind assertions to avoid being surrounded by additional periods:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    while (
        m/( 
            (?<!\.)\b
            (?:
                (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\b\.?
            ){4}
            \b(?<!\.)(?!\.)
        )/xg
        )
    {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
This is the IP I want 10.12.1.23, but when I did the
snmp walk the 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 variable came back null
```

Outputs:

```
10.12.1.23
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an IP address extraction REGEX that I have used often. It covers all the bases for valid IP address matching:

```
/(?<![\d\.])((2[0-4][0-9]\.|25[0-5]\.|[01]\d\d\.|\d\d\.|\d\.){3}(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[01]\d\d|\d\d|\d))(?![\d\.])/
```

It will match four distinct octets, separated by periods. The numbers included for each octet must match 0-255, but may also be prefixed with 1 or 2 zeroes (01, 01, 001, 011).

It will NOT match if the address is preceded with or followed by a digit or period.

Here is a script you can use to test it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
    print &checkIP ($_) . "\n";
}

# Bullet-proof IP Address extraction:
# This will look for IP addresses, each octet matching a range of 0-255, with
# contingencies for preceding zeroes (01, 001 ..These should be considered valid).
# Additionally, it ensures that it is not preceded or followed by a period
# or a digit (making the element 4 digits).
# The caveat is that this will only match the first IP address on a given line.
# This can be remedied by adding /g and capturing the matches in an array.
sub checkIP {
    my $l  = shift;
    my $out;
    return $1 if ($l =~ /(?<![\d\.])((2[0-4][0-9]\.|25[0-5]\.|[01]\d\d\.|\d\d\.|\d\.){3}(2[0-4] [0-9]|25[0-5]|[01]\d\d|\d\d|\d))(?![\d\.])/);
    chomp ($l);
    return "INVALID: " . $l;
}
```

Here is a break-down of the REGEX, in case anyone is interested:

```
# DO NOT MATCH ON supposed IP addresses preceded by a digit or a period.
/(?<![\d\.])
# FIRST THREE OCTETS MATCH:
# MATCH ON:
#   3-digit numbers beginning with 2, but only up to 249 preceding a period
#   OR 3-digit numbers beginning with 25, but only 250-255 preceding a period
#   OR 3-digit numbers beginning with 0 or 1 preceding a period
#   OR 2-digit numbers preceding a period
#   OR 1 digit numbers preceding a period
#   MATCH EXACTLY 3 TIMES.
((2[0-4][0-9]\.|25[0-5]\.|[01]\d\d\.|\d\d\.|\d\.){3}
# FINAL OCTET MATCH:
#   3-digit numbers beginning with 2, but only up to 249
#   OR 3-digit numbers beginning with 25, but only 250-255
#   OR 3-digit numbers beginning with 0 or 1
#   OR 2-digit numbers
#   OR 1 digit numbers
(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[01]\d\d|\d\d|\d))
# DO NOT MATCH if the next character is a digit or a period:
(?![\d\.])/
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to exclude numbers that contain too many "octets": ##.##.##.##.##, you can use look-arounds to exclude those portions. You can also use word boundaries such as `\b` to prevent **99`127.0.0.1`** from being captured:

```
(
  (?<!\d\.) # Ensure octet has no preceding '##.'
  \b        # Word boundary to exclude ##127.

  # first 3 ip (with optional [.] (.) \{.\} )
  (?:
    (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
    \(*\[*\{*\.\)*\]*\}*
  ){3}

  # last octet
  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)

  \b        # Word boundary to exclude .255##
  (?!\.\d)  # Ensure octet has no trailing '.##'
)
```

You can see an example [here](http://regex101.com/r/cA3eS3/6).

Throw some various text in there and check whether it gives you back the results you expect.

Comment: Thanks OnlineCop.  Thanks for documenting the look ahead and behinds